# Importing a firestore map in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to import firestore data in bigquery. Unfortunatly I have some map fields and I'm failing to tell bigquery to treat those fields as json. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays
For example, I have collection with the following objects
[{id: 1, name: 'whatever', users: {john: true}}, {id: 2, name: 'whatever1', users: {johny: true}}]

When I try to import this bigquery fails as it tries to create columns john, johny etc... What do I need to do, to force bigquery to treat users either as plain text or as json?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery does not support maps in JSON, you following “product” : {“my_product” : 40.0} will be invalid. Instead you should specify it as “product” : {“column1” : “my_product”, “column2” : “40.0”}. Also, there are other limitations such as newline delimited and other limitations mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations).